# VBscript find character " in a text

Tags: vbscript

I need to find the character " into text

I have used `InStr(strLine,""")`  but it doesn't run and gives me an error:

```
800a0409 unterminated string constant
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About using Double quotes in Vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770599/about-using-double-quotes-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is use *two* quote characters in a row, not just *one*:

```
InStr(strLine,"""")
```

This is how it breaks down:  the first `"` character is how you start a string constant; the second and third `"` characters together are called an "escaped" quote and indicate that you are not ending the string constant but are instead including a literal, single `"` character; the fourth `"` character is the final one indicating that you are ending the string constant.

You must always have an *even* number of quote characters `"` as a rule to avoid the compiler error you received.

As an alternative, you could also do it like this:

```
InStr(strLine, Chr(34))
```

[The `Chr()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws6aa3sf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) takes an ASCII value for a character and returns that character.  The ASCII value for the double-quote character `"` is 34.

Which approach you choose is up to you and depends on the circumstances.  I usually go with the escaped, double-double-quote `""` because it's easier to code and easier to read in longer string constants.