# VBA Formula w/ Relative Reference

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running into an issue using the following VBA formula. The code was working until I changed

```
IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,ListPrice,11,FALSE)=0,VLOOKUP(RC1,ListPrice,12,FALSE),VLOOKUP(RC1,ListPrice,11,FALSE)),0)*RC6
```

to

```
iferror(IF(RC11="",RC12,RC11),0)*(RC6/IF(RC8="",1,RC8)
```

Thanks for your help!

**Complete VBA:**

```
Sub STDCOST()
Dim LastRow As Long
Sheets("EXPIRE").Select
Range("n1").Value = "Ext_Cost"
Range("n2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC11="",RC12,RC11),0)*(RC6/IF(RC8="",1,RC8)"


Range("I1").Select

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
End With
Range("n2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("n2:n" & LastRow)
Columns("n:n").Select
Range("n:n").Style = "Currency"
End Sub
```

Comment: brackets mismatch?  You have 4 left brackets and 3 right brackets so expression is not valid.

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: `Range("n2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC11="",RC12,RC11),0)*(RC6/IF(RC8="",1,RC8)"` needs to be `Range("n2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(RC11="""",RC12,RC11),0)*(RC6/IF(RC8="""",1,RC8))"`  (i.e. missing bracket and double double-quotation marks)

Comment: Thanks everyone! @YowE3K, how come double-double quotations are necessary here?

Comment: @andrew green: on double quotes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770599/about-using-double-quotes-in-vbscript

Comment: @SMeaden Thank you!!