# Writing a VBS via another VBS

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a VBS via another VBS, but cant handle the quotation marks, and would love to know if it's even possible.

That's the 1 line I need in my new VBS:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Main VBS code that doesn't work:

```
    Dim oFSO, vbFile
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set vbFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("try.vbs", True)
    vbFile.WriteLine ""CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False""
    vbFile.Close
```

Comment: If you need to write out a quote character use; Chr(34)

Comment: @Sorceri Mind explaining? I added it at the start and at the end but it didn't help

Comment: `vbFile.WriteLine "CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "Wscript.Shell" & Chr(34) & ").Run "`   you should be able to get the rest from there

Comment: @Sorceri Just had to add a few more quotation marks, thanks!

Comment: You should post what you did as an answer;  Will help you get a few more points and allow you to have more actions on SO for future questions/answers. - Will also help anyone else down the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About using Double quotes in Vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770599/about-using-double-quotes-in-vbscript)

Comment: @GeertBellekens Not really, the solution here was quiet different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sorceri, I managed to make it work by writing the following code:

```
Dim oFSO, vbFile
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set vbFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile("try.vbs", True)
vbFile.WriteLine "CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "Wscript.Shell" & Chr(34) & ").Run """""""" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """""""", 0, False"
vbFile.Close
```

Answer (score -3):

This is what you need to do.

Copy and paste this code

```
do
msgbox("haha you cant close this")
CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run(".\Duplicate.vbs")
loop
```