# How do I add an argument in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, arguments

```
CreateObject("wscript.shell").run """C:\Program Files (x86)\2BrightSparks\SyncBackFree\SyncBackFree.exe"""
```

The above command works, but the following does not work.

```
CreateObject("wscript.shell").run """C:\Program Files (x86)\2BrightSparks\SyncBackFree\SyncBackFree.exe" -m "Back up a USB device"""
```

How do I make the argument **-m "Back up a USB device"** work?

Comment: By getting the escaped quotes right. `CreateObject("wscript.shell").run """C:\Program Files (x86)\2BrightSparks\SyncBackFree\SyncBackFree.exe"" -m ""Back up a USB device"""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
CreateObject("wscript.shell").run """%ProgramFiles(x86)%\2BrightSparks\SyncBackFree\SyncBackFree.exe ""-m"" Back up a USB device"""
```

Double quotes : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15784798/9556248)