# How can I send " sign from vbs?

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys

So I have this code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{"}"
```

But VBS says there is a mistake. How can I fix this?

I was trying to put it in {} but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message and any other information you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About using Double quotes in Vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770599/about-using-double-quotes-in-vbscript)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can. Wscript will think it is a syntax error every time. Unless you want to send two quotes it might not work. This might help with that.
[About using Double quotes in Vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770599/about-using-double-quotes-in-vbscript?noredirect=1&lq=1)